# tron: Just created address caused frequently used contract and extra fee

Tags: tron

I created address, sent trc20 to there and when tried to send it back, it took 31895 energy and explanation:

```
This transaction triggered a frequently used contract and caused 17,245 extra Energy consumption
```

How to not trigger then?

UPD
here is [example](https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/7661bb803a4fd0dece2b74fad21e73cf4d13e52f33a8248fd9325fc93e6b33e6)